# pycharm does not see system interpretator

Tags: pycharm, pythoninterpreter

My Ubuntu 18 has Python 2.7 and 3.6 versions only. If I call /usr/bin/python3 or /usr/bin/python3.6 in the console terminal - python 3.6 is run.

I installed pycharm 2023.1. The pycharm does not see python3.6 at all. Entering /usr/bin/python3 (or python3, or python) in the pycharm terminal runs python 3.10. However, outside the pycharm I does not found python3.10 anywhere.
If click Browse button in the pycharm Python Interpretator setting - files list of "/usr/bin" folder is opened. And there is no /usr/bin/python3.6 or /usr/bin/python2.7 in the list. But /usr/bin/python3.10 is present in the file list. (Outside the pycharm I does not found /usr/bin/python3.10).

I need to use python 3.6 in the pycharm - how can I do it?

Comment: There is only one solution that I found - downgrade to Pycharm 2022.3